# How to add an image before a radio input in jsonschema-form lib?

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, radio-button, jsonschema

I'm using [jsonschema-form lib](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form) and I would like to add an image before a radio input.

This image is an example of the final result:

[image]

My JSONSchema is:

```
"type": "object",
"title": "Title",
"properties": {
   "turni": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "radio",
      "enum": ["optA", "optB", "optC"],
      "enumNames": ["a", "b", "c"],
      "images":["url-a", "url-b", "url-c"]
   }
}
```

How I can customize a radio widget for my purpouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue in this way:

```
    "turns": {
        "type": "string",
        "represents": "turns",
        "enum": "option1", "option2", "option3"],
        "enumNames": ["a", "b", "c"],
        "uniqueItems": true,
        "imgs":["data:image/png;base64,...", 
                "data:image/png;base64,...",
                "data:image/png;base64,..."
               ]
        }
```